# Recreate Vue component (v-dialog) when button is clicked

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hey I am looking for a way to destroy and recreate v-dialog component. The use case is I want to show 'Create Member' dialog with first name etc fields. The dialog will be opened after click the button (activator slot). When the dialog is closed and reopened it shouldn't carry over state like entered first name previously.

**What I came up with so far**

1. When the popup is visible reset `data()` fields. People suggest doing that for each field which is not very scalable. Is there a way to have a factory function creating `data()`? However some elements could also carry over some ui states which is not hold directly in dialog data()..
2. Use `:key` on a v-dialog component which requires defining per dialog instance key and leaking the variable into parent component + changing the key when button is clicked etc.
3. Using some kind of a wrapper like `<DestroyableDialog>` (I came up with this name) which would just do all the magic when buton is clicked via activator slot.

```
<DestroyableDialog>
   <v-dialog>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
        <v-btn v-on="on">
          Create Member
        </v-btn>
    </template>
   <v-dialog/>
</DestroyableDialog>
```

4. Another option would be to have a way to create v-dialog programmatically and pass props and event handlers etc.. which might the most scalable way for large applications..

Comment: You might be able to use keep-alive for this. https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/keep-alive.html#lifecycle-of-cached-instance